# polynomial with an irrational expression of the free term

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I have problem with solving:

$x^3-2x-4\sqrt{6}=0$

I have no idea how to solve it. I transform it to $x(x-\sqrt{2})(x+\sqrt{2})=4\sqrt{6}$ but I'm stuck here

Comment: Moving the constant over to the other side and factoring will *never* give you anything useful. Remember that the reason we factor the $f$ in $f(x)=0$ is to use the convenient fact that if a product is zero, one of the factors must be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea: put $\;6^{1/2}\,t=x\;$ and the eq. becomes

$$6\sqrt6\,t^3-2\sqrt 6\,t-4\sqrt 6=0\stackrel{\text{divide by}\;2\sqrt6}\implies 3t^3-t-2=0$$

The rightmost equation's clearly the root $\;t=1\;$ , so we divide

$$3t^3-t-2=(t-1)(3t^2+3t+2)\;\ldots\;etc.$$

Of course, note that

$$t=1\implies x=\sqrt6$$

Comment: You made a little mistake: $t=1$ gives you $x=6^{1/2}=\sqrt 6$.

Comment: Of course, @ChristophPegel. Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{eqnarray}{\rm Put}\,\ \ x = \sqrt{X}\ \ \,{\rm in} \ \ (x^2-\,2)\ x\ \  &=& 4\sqrt 6\\ \Rightarrow\ (\color{#0a0}{X-2})\sqrt{\color{#c00}X} &=& \color{#0a0}4\sqrt{\color{#c00}6}\,\ \ {\rm so}\ \ \color{#c00}X\, =\ \ldots\ \rm is\ a\ solution.\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 0):

$x_1=\sqrt{6}.$

Then $x^3-2x-4\sqrt{6}$ devide by $(x-\sqrt{6})$

$$\dfrac{x^3-2x-4\sqrt{6}}{x-\sqrt{6}}=x^2+\sqrt{6}x+4$$

Comment: you've guessed that $\sqrt{6}$ is a root?

Comment: Guessing factors of the constant term is always a good start, so in this case $\pm 2$, $\pm 4$, $\pm \sqrt 6$ or even $\pm\sqrt 3$ and $\pm\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Yes, I really considered factors of the constant term, but Don Antonio's best solution